# xmlTextWriter does not save the XML file to bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, xmltextwriter

I am trying to create an XML file for storing some info from  a class. I gave the path as a const set to `Info.xml`. but the `XMLTextWriter` is not saving the XML file to bin(debug/release) folder, rather it is saving it to MyDocuments folder. When i tried to check if the file exists with `File.Exists(path)`, its returning false. Could somebody please guide me here.

My code looks as below...

```
string BookName = "Book1" 
string AuthorName= "Author1" 
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Info.xml", Encoding.UTF8);    writer.WriteStartDocument(); 
writer.WriteStartElement("Title"); 
writer.WriteString(BookName); 
writer.WriteStartElement("Author"); 
writer.WriteString(AuthorName); 
writer.WriteEndElement(); 
writer.WriteEndElement(); 
writer.WriteEndDocument(); 
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Posting code is always helpful...

Comment: Can you post the code that you have used?

Comment: I think you can use Application.StartupPath + Info.xml to save and also read or find File.Exists! like for example `Lineds.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath + @"//" + testPlanName + ".xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    public void SerializeToXML(YourClass yourObj)
    {
        if (!File.Exists("C:\\Info.xml"))
            File.Create("C:\\Info.xml");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));
        System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\Info.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, yourObj);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

This would save "Info.xml" to your C:, neither in debug nor in release. (It would also create file if doesn't already exists).

Check out this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436532/How-to-get-path-of-a-Application-file-in-winforms) as well, it might help.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the quick response,

Comment: My code looks as below...string BookName = "Book1"
string AuthorName= "Author1"


XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Info.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

writer.WriteStartElement("Title");
writer.WriteString(BookName);

writer.WriteStartElement("Author");
writer.WriteString(AuthorName);
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am developing a COM addIn and Application.startupPath gives me the path "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14"

Comment: @Sri how are you saving the file? Could you edit your question & post your code? If you are not giving anything except the file name as path, any com application is going to save it in it's default location.

Comment: Hi Devraj, I have updated my question above with the code i am using.

Comment: when i use "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()", I am getting the path of bin directory. I hope this solves my problem. Thanks for your help....

Comment: I would suggest you save your file in folder returned by -Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData). As there might be some permission issues in future. Also you can save your file wherever you want by specifying the full path in - XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Info.xml", Encoding.UTF8); See my edited answer.

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) works for me. Thanks so much for the help Devraj.